# For loops not completing in python 3 Discord.py bot mass DM failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, discord, discord.py

For some reason or another, on my discord.py bot for-loops don't seem to want to complete. The point of the loop is to send the same message to about 20 users. The problem is that some users aren't getting these messages and I'm fairly confident that the problem is in the loop.

```
for server_member in ctx.message.server.members:
    await client.send_message(server_member, message)
```

I don't have much experience with for-loops so in my eyes this seems like the most likely problem.

This is the error code left behind after every attempt to send the message.

```
Ignoring exception in command massdm
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\%myuseraccount%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
ret = yield from coro(args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\%myuseraccount%\Desktop\assistbot.py", line 36, in massdm
await client.send_message(server_member, message)
File "C:\Users\%myuseraccount%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 1152, in send_message
data = yield from self.http.send_message(channel_id, content, 
guild_id=guild_id, tts=tts, embed=embed)
File "C:\Users\%myuseraccount%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 196, in request
raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Cannot send messages 
to this user
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\%myuseraccount%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in 
process_commands
yield from command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\%myuseraccount%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in invoke
yield from injected(ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\%myuseraccount%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 54, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: 
Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Cannot send messages to this user
```

Comment: What makes you think the error is in the loop? Have you tried to put some debug messages?

Comment: Why are you confident it is the loop? There's nothing special about this specific loop, really.

Comment: `for code in code_that_doesnt_work: debug_code()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord users have the ability to prevent direct messages from servers they chosen. The for-loop itself isn't the problem, your bot can't message people who disabled the following:

[image]
(The same apply for desktop discord)

This is why discord.py is raising this error:

```
Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Cannot send messages to this user
```

You need to catch this error so that the loop keeps going, and message every other users:

```
for server_member in ctx.message.server.members:
    try:
        await client.send_message(server_member, message)
    except discord.Forbidden:
        pass
```

Comment: This is the problem for some people, but there are others who have gotten messages at earlier times and not gotten them later.

Comment: `server.members` isn't static, the order can differs every time you start the bot. The members you mentioned could used to be on the top of the list (before the problematic member that caused the error), and now they're at the bottom (the loop broke when the error is raised, so the bot never sent them the message). When there's an uncaught error, the code will break — so your loop never finished. Just use my last code example, it solves your problem by catching the exception and ignoring it.